# Format clock variables from a char string in C

Tags: string, time, format, strtok, arduino-c++

I'm using a library function which returns a Char * value.

The value is a date string sent back from a modem that looks like this:

"+QLTS: "2022/11/16,09:51:56+32,0"

I'm trying to use the strtok function to obtain the hour and minute only and store these as integers into a variables "hour" and "min".

The 24 hour tokens come back fine, however the next step is to format the hour or min should they be returned as "09" (9am) for example. In this case i'm trying to knock off the "0" in "09" should a 0 be detected as the first value.

I had a crack at it but having compiling issues with converting string types.

So if the hour is 09 or 9am,  this needs to be returned as a 9 only, same with the minutes.

If anyone could give me a hand I'd be most appreciative.

Thanks in advance

Please note the variables int t_hour & int t_min will eventually be made global.

```
    char * time_buffer = (char *)fona.getTime();
    char hour_tok[2];
    char min_tok[2];
    int t_hour;
    int t_min;
        
        if (strcmp(time_buffer, "ERROR") != 0) // 
        {   
            strtok(time_buffer, ",");
            hour_tok = strtok(NULL, ",");  
                
            strtok(hour_tok, ":"); 
            min_tok = strtok(NULL, ":"); 
            
            if(hour_tok[0] == "0")
            {
             t_hour = atoi(hour_tok[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                t_hour = atoi(hour_tok);
            }
            
            
            if(min_tok[0] == "0")
            {
             t_min = atoi(min_tok[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                t_min = atoi(min_tok);
            }

            Serial.println(F("<<<<<TIME HR>>>>"));
            Serial.println(String(t_hour));
            Serial.println(F("<<<<<TIME MIN>>>>"));
            Serial.println(String(t_min));
```

Comment: [`strptime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html)

Comment: The function `atoi` requires a pointer to a string. Instead, you are passing the value of a single character (i.e. not a pointer).

Comment: I don't see your problem with the leading zero. Calling `atoi( "09" );` will give you the value `9` as an `int`. Whether it has a leading zero or not is only a matter of how you later print it.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that suggestion worked perfectly!

Comment: look-up the `sscanf` function

Comment: Thanks Juraj, and Andrew